# How to add external CSS while generating PDF using iTextSharp.LGPLv2.Core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, itext, asp.net-core-mvc

I am generating PDF using iTextSharp.LGPLv2.Core, but the problem is that I am not able to apply that CSS.
Currently, I am using following code to generate PDF

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
TextReader txtReader = new StringReader(pHTML);            
Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 25, 25, 25, 25);

PageEventHelper e = new PageEventHelper();
doc.SetMargins(doc.LeftMargin, doc.RightMargin, 35, 0);
iTextSharp.text.Image addLogo = default(iTextSharp.text.Image);
addLogo = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(wwwroot + "\\Medical\\images\\logo.png");

PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, ms);
pdfWriter.PageEvent = e;
addLogo.ScaleToFit(128, 80);
addLogo.Alignment = iTextSharp.text.Image.ALIGN_LEFT;
doc.Open();
doc.Add(addLogo);
HtmlWorker htmlWorker = new HtmlWorker(doc);
htmlWorker.StartDocument();
htmlWorker.Parse(txtReader);
htmlWorker.EndDocument();
htmlWorker.Close();
doc.Close();
```

With this, I'm able to generate PDF. 
bur how can I add an external css file.

Comment: The version you are using is completely obsolete. It doesn't support the functionality you require, and as it has been declared "end of life" many years ago, that functionality will never be implemented for that version. Please upgrade to iText 7 and the pdfHTML add-on, and make sure to remove all instances of iTextSharp versions prior to version 5 for [reasons explained in the iText FAQ](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/versions-older-than-5).

Comment: @Bruno but it is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0

Comment: Are you sure? What have you tried?

Comment: Yes, I tried and iTextSharp.LGPLv2.Core 1.3.0 publish date was Thursday, June 08, 2017

Comment: That version is not endorsed by iText Group. It is an unofficial release based on a version of iTextSharp that has known technical and legal issues. If I were you, I wouldn't use it. I would only use official iText ® versions.

Comment: There are almost no free html to pdf converts for .Net core and this seems to be the only library that does it at this point. But importing styling has also been a major issue for me.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie Are there any Itext libraries that are supported by .net core applications that supporting importing a style sheet?

Comment: Are you creating free software? If not, then why are you looking for free HTML to PDF conversion?